# Why is `std::invoke` not constexpr?

Tags: c++, std, invoke, constexpr, c++17

Shouldn't [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) be `constexpr` especially after [constexpr lambdas in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Are there any obstacles that will prevent this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** [P1065](https://wg21.link/p1065) will make it `constexpr`.

---

**Keep original post for historical reason:**

From [the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html):

> Although there is possibility to implement standard conforming invoke function template as a constexpr function, the proposed wording does not require such implementation. The main reason is to left it consistent with existing standard function objects, that could have such definition, like std::mem_fn, std::reference_wrapper and operator wrappers. Furthermore imposing such requirement will block the implementation of invoke that refers to std::mem_fn.
>
> This proposal assumes that constexpr addition to the  header would be applied consistently by a separate proposal.
>
> Both constexpr and standard library based implementation are presented in Implementability section of the proposal.

---

Related CWG issue #1581: [**When are `constexpr` member functions defined?**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581).