# Why can pointers to non-static member functions not be used as a unary predicate for standard library algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, std, pointer-to-member

Many algorithms from the standard library accept a unary predicate with a signature of `bool (Type & item)` so supplying a pointer to a non-static member function directly is not working. This seems to be rather restrictive considering that it seems to be possible to lift such a restriction by replacing direct invocation of `operator ()` on the predicate with a call to `std::invoke`. Maybe the proposed approach has some drawbacks that I've overlooked?

Note: the non-static member function referred to in this question is supposed to differ from a regular function predicate only in that an item reference is passed as an implicit parameter rather than an explicit parameter.

Example code ([online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lXTtW1DLOF2kYpXi)):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

template<typename TForwardIterator, typename TPredicate> TForwardIterator
my_find_if
(
    const TForwardIterator p_items_begin
,   const TForwardIterator p_items_end
,   TPredicate &&          predicate
)
{
    TForwardIterator p_item(p_items_begin);
//  while((p_items_end != p_item) && (!predicate(*p_item)))
    while((p_items_end != p_item) && (!::std::invoke(predicate, *p_item)))
    {
        ++p_item;
    }
    return(p_item);
}

class t_Ticket
{
    private: int m_number;

    public:
    t_Ticket(const int number): m_number(number) {}

    public: bool
    Is_Lucky(void) const {return(8 == m_number);}
};

int main()
{
    ::std::array<t_Ticket, 10> tickets{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //  using standard library
    auto p_ticket1(::std::find_if(tickets.begin(), tickets.end(), [](const t_Ticket & ticket) {return(ticket.Is_Lucky());}));
    //  still works
    auto p_ticket2(my_find_if(tickets.begin(), tickets.end(), [](const t_Ticket & ticket) {return(ticket.Is_Lucky());}));
    //  same thing, but shorter and not sufferring from potential lambda code duplication
    auto p_ticket3(my_find_if(tickets.begin(), tickets.end(), &t_Ticket::Is_Lucky));
    //  using standard library like this won't compile
    //auto p_ticket4(::std::find_if(tickets.begin(), tickets.end(), &t_Ticket::Is_Lucky));

    assert(p_ticket1 == p_ticket2);
    assert(p_ticket2 == p_ticket3);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: There's a proposal for [](auto&& t) -> t.IsLucky(), which is as condensed as it's likely to get. Note that it's also more general: -> t.sLucky(1) || t.isLucky(2) works as well. Maybe one day we'll have '@' representing auto&& for variables (and maybe using for types).

Comment: FWIW, there's also [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Comment: `bool Is_Lucky(void) const {return(8 == m_number);}` - `return` is not a function. Those parentheses are not needed. `return 8 == m_number;` is (IMHO) more idiomatic. Also, that `void` to indicate no function arguments is a C-ism - don't do that in C++ - just `bool Is_Lucky() const` will do.

Comment: @lorro What `[](auto&& t) -> t.IsLucky()` is supposed to do? Is it a lambda with `{return();}` thrown away?

Comment: @VTT it's proposed to mean the same as: [](auto&& t) -> decltype(t.isLucky()) { return t.isLucky(); }

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, assuming that the question is:

> Why can't algorithms take a generic `Callable` as their predicate/action?

I can think of multiple reasons:

- The `Callable` concept was introduced in C++11 - pre-C++11 algorithms were not designed with it in mind.
- Accepting any `Callable` would require expanding concepts such as [`Predicate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate) and allowing algorithms to conditionally take an additional argument for *pointers to member functions*. This might lead to unnecessary complexity that can be avoided by simply restricting the interface to `FunctionObject` and forcing the user to do the "binding".
- This would increase the amount of overloads significantly, considering that there also are execution policy overloads now. Alternatively, it could make every algorithm a *variadic template* where the *parameter pack* can contain either zero or one arguments (in case `*this` needs to be provided for a `Callable`).
- [`std::invoke` is not `constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222989/why-is-stdinvoke-not-constexpr). Using it might prevent algorithms to be marked as `constexpr` in the future.

---

If you are referring to the particular case where:

- The algorithm operates over a homogeneous range of `T`.
- The predicate is executed on every element of type `T` of the range.
- `T` has a member function that could be used as a predicate.

Then, I can still think of some possible reasons:

- `std::invoke` is still not `constexpr`. We could avoid using `std::invoke` for `.*`, but then we would need to provide two separate implementations per algorithm.
- If the member function is a `template` or an *overload set*, then this would fail to compile and confuse beginners. Generic lambdas do not have this issue.
- It would complicate the requirements for algorithms - there would need to be some sort of restriction on the type/signature of the member function that makes sure it is usable on the range of `T`.

Or maybe... it just hasn't been proposed yet. If you still think it's a valuable thing to have after the reasons I came up with, you can start here in order to learn how to write a proposal: https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal

Comment: Why are additional overloads needed for member functions? It's a template already, why change?

Comment: @Rakete1111: you would have to pass the instance on which to invoke the member function as well. E.g. `std::remove_if(fst, last, &foo::some_predicate, my_foo_instance)`.

Comment: Wouldn't `&foo::some_predicate` be called on the values of the range, and not on another instance?

Comment: (2) My question implies that non-static member function used as predicate differs from `bool (Type & item)` function in that an item reference is passed as an implicit parameter. (3) more like marking `std::invoke` as `constexpr` would be required to mark algorithms with `constexpr`

Comment: @VTT: `std::invoke` cannot be marked as `constexpr` due to a CWG issue. Check the link in my answer.

Comment: But the first sentence says "there is possibility to implement standard conforming invoke function template as a constexpr function". And the counter arguments include difficulties with dealing with `mem_fn` that has been removed anyway. Though i'm not sure what CWG stands for.

Comment: @VTT: again, it's in the link I posted. [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581). Until this CWG (core working group) issue is resolved, `std::invoke` cannot be marked as `constexpr`.